# errors with pyautogui on Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, anaconda, spyder, pyautogui

I am wanting to use pyautogui to automate some tasks but i am having trouble getting the package to work on Windows 7.

I am currently using anaconda and spyder (i have also tried python IDLE). I can install the pyautogui package without any errors, but when i try to run a simple command:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.displayMousePosition()
```

The above i got from a youtube video of Al Sweigart doing a demo of pyautogui, and from the outcome i would expect to see the x, y coordinates of the mouse pointer and the R,G,B numbers.

But when I run it I get the following messages:

```
runfile('C:/Users/david/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/david/.spyder-py3')
Reloaded modules: pymsgbox, pyautogui, pyautogui._pyautogui_win, pymsgbox._native_win, pymsgbox.native, pyscreeze, pytweening
Press Ctrl-C to quit.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-0007268e4f6f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/david/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/david/.spyder-py3')

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/david/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 2, in <module>
    pyautogui.displayMousePosition()

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 1027, in displayMousePosition
    pixelColor = pyscreeze.screenshot().getpixel((x, y))

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 309, in _screenshot_win32
    im = ImageGrab.grab()

NameError: name 'ImageGrab' is not defined
```

I have tried manually installing the dependenciies (pillow) in case that was the issue, but I cannot figure out how to fix the problem. I know the above message give a lot of info but I don't understand well enough to fix the issue.

Can anyone help? or tell me where i'm going wrong?